# Django Templates - Rendering to an Iterator

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a django view which uses a template to display a long queryset (> 800 items). It takes several seconds for the view to render, and when it's done rendering the entire page, it sends it to the browser. Instead, I want the Template to render as an iterator, so that it can transmit the page line by line (and so I can see the page appear in my browser) as it is generated. I don't want to wait several seconds before I see anything.

Right now my view returns `render_to_response('view_name.html', {items:myitems})`.

Is rendering a template to an iterator as I've described possible in Django?

Comment: Besides the solutions proposed by jdi... Have you looked at the query that is generated by your queryset? Maybe you can do some optimisation there as well? Does your query hit the database more than one time (eg. for displaying relationships)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not via templates, no.

You can treat an HttpResponse as an iterator, yielding your output line-by-line, but template rendering is an all-in-one process (as it has to be, because of the need to resolve blocks etc).

Answer (score 1):

Your options would be to use pagination:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/

Or to use ajax. You would load your page and then request the data over an ajax request. Check out jquery.

*Edit* 
Adding more links
Here is an example of someone using jquery and an HttpResponse with an iterator: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ajax-partial-response

Here is an example of someone returning a chunked response from a file on the filesystem:
http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/365/

Comment: +1 for suggesting ajax ... but does Django support rendering to an iterator?

Comment: No. I think you would have to do something manually where you create an iterator that represents the whole page. That is, the items are all rendered in chunks in your iterator. And then you would pass that to an HttpResponse